# Beautifulsoup bs.find_all('a') not working on a webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, findall

Could someone please explain exactly if there is a way to scrape links from this webpage https://hackmd.io/@nearly-learning/near-201 using BeautifulSoup or is it only possible with Selenium?

```
url = 'https://hackmd.io/@nearly-learning/near-201' 
html = urlopen(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'lxml') # also tried all other parcers 
links = bs.find_all('a') # only obtains 23 links, when there are actually loads more.
for link in links: 
    if 'href' in link.attrs:
        print(link.attrs['href'])
```

Only obtain a few links and non in the actual body of the article.

I am however able to do it with Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://hackmd.io/@nearly-learning/near-201")
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
for elem in elems:
    print(elem.get_attribute("href"))
```

But would like to use BeautifulSoup if possible! Who knows if it is?

Comment: BeautifulSoup processes mark-up text... so is an "off-line" processing tool. I guess you mean if it possible with `urllib.request.urlopen`

Comment: The issue isn't with beautifulsoup.  The issue is how you're fetching the page content. `urlopen()` doesn't process javascript, but selenium does.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use `selenium`, you can use [`Markdown`](https://pypi.org/project/Markdown/) package to render the markdown text to HTML and parse it with BeautifulSoup:

```py
import markdown  # pip install Markdown
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# 1. get raw markdown text
url = "https://hackmd.io/@nearly-learning/near-201"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
md_txt = soup.select_one("#doc").text

# 2. render the markdown to HTML
html = markdown.markdown(md_txt)

# 3. parse it again and find all <a> links
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for a in soup.select("a[href]"):
    print(a["href"])
```

Prints:

```
https://cdixon.org/2018/02/18/why-decentralization-matters
https://docs.near.org/docs/concepts/gas#ballpark-comparisons-to-ethereum
https://docs.near.org/docs/roles/integrator/exchange-integration#blocks-and-finality
https://docs.near.org/docs/concepts/architecture/papers
https://explorer.near.org/nodes/validators
https://explorer.near.org/stats
https://docs.near.org/docs/develop/contracts/rust/intro
https://docs.near.org/docs/develop/contracts/as/intro
https://docs.near.org/docs/api/rpc

...and so on.
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned it needs `selenium` or something similar to render all the content and sure you could use `selenium` and `BeautifulSoup` in da mix, if you prefer to select your elements in that way.

Just push the `driver.page_source` to your `BeautifulSoup()`

```
bs = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://hackmd.io/@nearly-learning/near-201")

bs = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)

for link in bs.select('a[href]'):
    print(link['href'])
```

Comment: The problem is I have loads of different pages I need to go over @HedgeHog. Thus it is going to be super slow to process each page in the way that opens up chrome every time.